# Excel VBA On Error Resume Next Returns Value Out Of Position

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I am placing picture in my worksheet using a URL. The code works great except "on error resume next" places the previous cell's (good) value in the cell where the error occurred instead of the cell it should (one row up). It then continues placing values where they belong until there is another error.

I have tried placing the "on error resume next" in different areas of the code, but haven't been able to fix the issue. Is it a matter of where the error handling is placed, or do I need to have a better error handler?

Thank you,
Andy

```
Sub InsertPic()
  On Error Resume Next 
  Dim pic As String 
  Dim myPicture As Picture 
  Dim rng As Range 
  Dim cl As Range 

Set rng = Range("F2:F1131")
For Each cl In rng
pic = cl.Offset(0, -1)

Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic)

With myPicture

    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Width = cl.Width
    .Height = cl.Height
    .Top = Rows(cl.Row).Top
    .Left = Columns(cl.Column).Left
End With

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if the URL exists then maybe a helper function will suffice?

```
Sub InsertPic()

  Dim pic As String 
  Dim myPicture As Picture 
  Dim rng As Range 'E3:E1132
  Dim cl As Range 'iterator

  Set rng = Range("F2:F1131")
  For Each cl In rng
    pic = cl.Offset(0, -1)

    if URLExists(pic) then
      Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic)
      With myPicture
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Width = cl.Width
        .Height = cl.Height
        .Top = Rows(cl.Row).Top
        .Left = Columns(cl.Column).Left
      End With
    end if
  Next

End Sub

'ref: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/567315-check-if-url-exists-so-then-return-true.html
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function
```

Comment: There are a number of missing images that the URL return a 404 error, so I incorporated the on error resume next, so it would push through the sheet.

Comment: @AndyAdams ok - does that error occur on a specific line of code? the line `Set myPicture =..`?

Comment: yep, and that is where I initially placed the on error resume next.

Comment: see my edit - I think it might be wise to skip the whole iterative block if it hits an error there

Comment: I get a run-time error with that. It breaks at Set myPicture... I have a meeting shortly, but thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: I tried your updated VBA, and it runs with no error, but the images don't populate either. Sorry I am very new to VBA.

Comment: @AndyAdams is the helper function returning false for each url? if you use F9 to put a stop in the code then hit F5 to run up to the stop, then step through one row at time - you can check values as you go by hovering the cursor over values or using the Immediate window.